# One-to-Many in Sonata admin bundle performence

Tags: sonata-admin

I am using symfony and sonata admin bundle. 
I have a one-to-many relationship. I am using sonata_type_collection from the admin class. 
I have about 5000 entries in the collection. This is comming up as a dropdown list with 5000 entries(normal). 
so entity_1 has a 1 to many relationship to entity_2(5000 entries in db)
I have 3 instances of entity_2 to my entity_1, so i get 3 drop downlist of 5000 each.
My app is taking about 20-30 seconds to load because of these 3 drop down list.

If i remove the reference to entiy_2 from entity_1 admin class my app takes about 5 seconds to load admin_1's page.

Does anyone have a clue what i can do to improve performence?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **autocomplete** field type:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model-autocomplete

It won't generate dropdowns until some values is provided. Not sure if it suits for your case, as you haven't mentioned anything about your models, relations etc.